Using message_lost_callbacks with wait sets
I have a lot of messages and have implemented a wait set subscriber based on the example found here: https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/rolling/rclcpp/wait_set/src/wait_set.cpp.
For my subscription options I’ve added a message lost callback like so
auto options = rclcpp::SubscriptionOptionsWithAllocator<AllocatorT>();
// Set callback for message lost statisitcs.
options.event_callbacks.message_lost_callback =
[](rclcpp::QOSMessageLostInfo &info) {
std::cout << “Lost messages: " << info.total_count << " total / " << info.total_count_change << " since last callback\n”;
};

and have updated the create_subscription lines in the example accordingly. From what I can tell my callback isn’t being invoked but I am encountering gaps in the publisher sequence number of the messages.
Do wait sets support calling event_callbacks whenever messages are evicted from the RMW queue?
Is there any way to get this to work?
Thank you,
Chris
